# Difference between directly using value and saving it as variable first

Tags: javascript

Is there a difference between

```
var investment = $("investment").value;
investment = parseFloat(investment);
```

and this

```
var investment = parseFloat($("investment").value);
```

I understand that the second example is more efficient. My question is, if the variable `investment` were to be later used as part of a formula, will there be any issue or difference depending on whether the conversion was done like in the first example as compared to the second?

Comment: No, they are identical (apart from using a temporary assignment).

Comment: @Amadan point out is correct. No difference, just like this a=1+2 , a =2+1.

Comment: 2 codes are same..

Comment: 2 codes are same but the second one is more efficient than the first one.

Comment: You have a logic error: `$("investment").value` will return the *value* property of the object returned by `$("investment")`, which is a native javascript Object, not a DOM element, so likely its *value* property will not be what you expect.

Comment: In this scenario there is minimal performance issue in cacheing the variable beforehand. However in other situations it may be worthwhile to cache it first, for example DOM manipulation etc, as you don't want to be making too many calls to the DOM on the same element, but rather pull it out first into memory, make the changes, then put it back in.

Comment: @char—there are no changes to the element, the OP is simply reading an object value. If there is any difference in performance, it will be insignificant unless there are several hundred thousand such operations more or less sequentially. By far the biggest issue for performance here is the use of jQuery, which requires creating an entire "jQuery" object and a function call to read a property that is likely available simply as a sequence of properties.

Comment: @RobG if you read my comment, I said in THIS scenario (referring to his value property scenario) that there is minimal performance issue. Then I stated another situation where cacheing prior can be more efficient.

Comment: @char - The OP's code isn't caching at all, it *immediately* overwrites the value that was in the same variable. The hypothetical other scenarios you have in mind probably don't involve caching the *value* either.

Comment: @nnnnnn In OP's first block, OP declares ```var investment = $('investment').value```, OP creates a reference which then is parsed as opposed to parsing the value then assigning reference. 
In regards to my hypothetical scenario, consider:
```for (i=0; i<document.getElementsByClass('mydiv'); i++) {
document.getElementsByclass[i].className='newClass'}```
As opposed to:
```var els = document.getElementsByClass('mydiv')
for (i=0; i<els.length; i++) { els[i].className = 'newClass'}```

Comment: @nisar If both these codes mean the same thing, why am I getting different results in the final computation? Have a look at future_value_1.js and future_value_2.js. These two javascript files and the html and css files can be found [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/8wdt90c4e7nq0e4/AAB_LVyGAsZnu2rPp5gxea-fa?dl=0). If you want to run these on your machine, remember to modify the    <script src"..."> tag to point to the appropriate js file.

Comment: @javaperson ...Got the same output by doing little bit changes, you assigned futureValue = investment ,before you are parsing investment ,just do parsing before assign futureValue . everything is fine..var investment = $("investment").value;
 var rate = $("rate").value;
 var years = $("years").value;
 investment = parseFloat(investment);
 var futureValue=investment;

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/3nxv5njhanjrtpq/AABUEsC3MO69rn4EH7ZidCaNa?dl=0